# Rearranging strings to minimise storage in a trie

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures

I'm currently thinking about the following problem.

### Problem

**Input:** a set $W$ of strings over an alphabet $\Sigma$.

**Goal:** permute the characters in each string so that the [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) that will contain the rearranged strings has as few edges as possible.

(by "permuting" and "rearranging", I mean that any permutation of the characters is valid).

### Example

Given strings $S=$"ABRACADABRA" and $T=$"BARRACUDA", storing them without rearrangement would require a trie of size 20, since they share no common prefix; however, if we are allowed to rearrange them, we can obtain the following optimal solution of size 12:

```
0-A-B-R-A-C-A-D-R-A-B-A (S')
                 \
                  U     (T')
```

(where 0 denotes the root, and $S'$ (resp. $T'$) is the rearranged $S$ (resp. $T$)).

### Question(s)

Has this problem been studied before, and can you give me references? What is its complexity (for $|W|\geq 3$; the problem is easy otherwise)?

Comment: What kinds of rearrangements do you permit? Arbitrary permutations?

Comment: @DaveClarke: Yes, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: I had the same question as Dave.  Can you edit the question so that people do not have to read the comments to understand what you are asking?

Comment: Do you have an application in mind?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: done! Raphael: assume you have to mine frequent patterns in a graph (i.e. extract subgraphs that occur at least $t$ times). Each extracted match is a set of edges, and the order of edges within a match does not matter. Matches must be stored and reported, and both the graph to mine and the set of extracted patterns can be quite large; this is one possible way of saving space.

Comment: In the graph example, you are storing *sets* of edges, while your question seems to suggest that you are storing *multisets* (i.e., your strings may contain the same character more than once). The case of sets sounds easier to me...

Comment: Is alphabet Σ fixed or specified as part of the input?  (Your comment suggests that it is part of the input.)

Comment: It is indeed part of the input.

Comment: Questions about the question usually imply that the question is not written clearly.  Please try to improve your question rather than just answering in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I'm wondering about was tackled long ago (1977) by Douglas Comer and Ravi Sethi, in a paper entitled ["The Complexity of Trie Index Construction"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322023). They show that the decision version of the above problem, as well as three other variants, are NP-complete.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, minimizing the size of the trie seems hard. However, when you change your objective function to maximizing the saved space you can easily get a 2-approximation.

For every pair of strings, count the number of characters they have in common. Then do a max cost matching weighted by the values computed before, and for each matched pair permute their characters so that their common prefix is as long as possible. The analysis is simple, right?